# Laravel 5.5 sending Email not responding smtp.gmail.com #10060

Tags: php, laravel, email, smtp, laravel-5.5

laravel 5.5 sending mail in website local server on windows(xampp)
this is my code sending

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xTKj0.png)

my Error

Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com [A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. #10060]

help me how to check this error exeption

MailController.php file

```
    public function index()
{
            Mail::send('mail.index', ['key' => 'value'], function($message)
    {
        $message->to('akambajalan0@gmail.com', 'Hello Akam ')->subject('Welcome!');
    });

    return view('mail.index');

}
```

.env file

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=578
MAIL_USERNAME=*myemail*@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=*mypassword*
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0R8OG.png)

Comment: post some code's instead of images

Comment: Which smtp port are you using in .env file for mail?

Comment: this is a code 

                Mail::send('mail.index', ['key' => 'value'], function($message)
        {
            $message->to('akambajalan0@gmail.com', 'Hello Akam ')->subject('Welcome!');
        });

        return view('mail.index');

Comment: .env file 

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=578
MAIL_USERNAME=akambajalan0@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=*mypassword*
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls

Comment: Are you sure your `MAIL_PASSWORD` == key you generated for 3rd party apps but not your password for gmail account?

Answer (score 0):

this is the whole thing about send email 
i think your problem is with the steam ssl

```
'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),
'stream' => [
    'ssl' => [
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false,
        'allow_self_signed' => true,
    ],
],
```

If you wanna send mail with the token you can make that and you can use

```
Route::post('/PasswordReset', 'ResetPasswordController@GetToken');
```

then send Token by mail where you can save token you may not even save it you can use the Username there is function called bcrypt(); you can hashing his username by it and it will give you long token but i dont prefer that bec the token wont change

i prefer send him new password to mail and make him login then change password you can use `str_random(8);` it will generate 8 random number with letters

Trying Help You First you must config your mail go to Config/mail.php and add this after driver

```
'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),
'stream' => [
    'ssl' => [
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false,
        'allow_self_signed' => true,
    ],
],
```

Second Go to you .env file change this to your host details list try with gmail one

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp

MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com

MAIL_PORT=587

MAIL_USERNAME=yourgmailMail@gmail.com

MAIL_PASSWORD=yourpassword

MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Third go to your Controller that you will make send mail function in lists Assume its name is SendMassEmailController This is the Whole Controller

last thing is the route go to web.php

```
Route::post('/SendMassEmail','SendMassEmailController@SendMassEmail');
```

Finally Good Luck and Have Fun

Comment: Replacing: smtp.gmail.com with 173.194.65.108
but iam  sure you missed up some thing from the up code i wrote
can you send me 
mail.php
bec i just test this now and it works for me with smtp